# .NET Framework External Method Source Code

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any way to see the source code for methods that are implemented externally in the .NET framework?

I know about [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) which is a great resource, however a lot of the core classes in the .NET framework are implemented externally (I assume in C++?).

For example I am very interested in the internal workings of of the class [String](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,8281103e6f23cb5c) but almost half of the methods are declared with the extern keyword including `this[int index]` which appears to actually hold the characters in the string.

Where can I find the source code for `String.this[int index]` or `String.nativeCompareOrdinalEx(String strA, int indexA, String strB, int indexB, int count)` and other externally implemented methods?

Also, is there a particular reason why so much of the core framework classes are implemented externally? Is it so that they could utilize existing code or for performance reasons or something else?

Comment: You've got to do some digging in the coreclr repo. For example, I believe `String.nativeCompareOrdinalEx` it is mapped to `COMString::CompareOrdinalEx` found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/bc146608854d1db9cdbcc0b08029a87754e12b49/src/classlibnative/bcltype/stringnative.cpp). Look at the [external call list](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/419629fdc3e51c6c28467bf1b57b7fcd80dc8360/src/vm/ecalllist.h) and try to find the function mapping.

Comment: @mikez The external call list is very helpful and is exactly what I am looking for. Any idea the mapping for `String.this[int index]`?

Comment: @JacobSchneider It might be `FCIntrinsic("get_Chars", COMString::GetCharAt, CORINFO_INTRINSIC_StringGetChar)` but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the new, community, version you can dig in the github, that's where I found the implementation of decimal subtraction (or were I was pointed to by SO in fact)

[CoreCLR / src](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/tree/de8b85b643ac08d69696ad078846424b69ae651f/src)

You have roslyn code there too:

[Roslyn at Github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn)

Comment: Using the CoreCLR in combination with the [mapping](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/bc146608854d1db9cdbcc0b08029a87754e12b49/src/classlibnative/bcltype/stringnative.cpp) that mikez pointed out gave me the source code exactly.